# Scroll view issue

Tags: iphone

friends

I develop one scroll view set its content size and set three view on scroll view and its scroll fine and i also want it move when segmentcontrol tap but it was not happen my view is not move on scroll can some one help me to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

hope i understand your question

try this

-(IBAction)SegmentControll:(id)sender

{

```
[myTableView removeFromSuperview];


if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==0) 

{

     Yourscollview.scrollEnabled=NO;

}
```

if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==1)

```
{

    Yourscollview.scrollEnabled=YES;

}
```

}

if need more help ask me.

Comment: Thanks for ans me I know this one now I want when user tap on segment contol view change and in between if user also want to scroll then what I can do that time scroll is disable so what can i do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Move your scroll-view with tap on the Segment-control...Here, I am providing you sample code...you just need to decide on which segment index you want to move scroll view...

```
 if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==0) 
{
 if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x <= self.scrollView.frame.size.width ) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x + self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    //pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
 }
}

else if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==1) 
{
 if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x >= self.scrollView.frame.size.width ) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    //pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
 }
}
```

I hope this will help you...

Comment: hey buddy can u tell me what means of pagecontrolBeginUsed because its not working in my code and thanks for reply.

Comment: its work fine thanks...but i just remove that pagecontrol what the use of that

Comment: in this solution i got one problem if user again tap segment one then view will not changed what chamge we should do for solve this problem

Comment: When User tap on segment control set self.scrollView.contentOffset.x according to your view position.For Example if you want scroll forward that increase your self.scrollView.contentOffset.x and if you want scroll backward than decrease your self.scrollView.contentOffset.x (self.scrollView.contentOffset.x-320)